# access level management for module in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

Isn't there acl order deny method for module. do i always have to add controller and index? i have an admin module and default module witch dozen controller in them and three dozen actions for them and it's really being wearisome

My code goes like this

```
class Management_Access extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        // set up acl
        $acl = new Zend_Acl();

        // add the roles
        $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'));
        $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('administrator'), 'guest');

        // add the resources
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('index'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('error'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('login'));

        //admin resources
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('destination'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('home'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('page'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('tour'));
        $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('hotel'));
```

isn't there a way to check if resource is registered in acl?

UPDATE::
i have eight controllers in my default module and nine controllers in 'admin' module.

i have index controller in admin module as well as in default module. if i add allow guest index, the guest is also able to access the index page in admin module. admin module is only set for administrator

Comment: Please specify more details, show us example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. check current module in controller plugin (`$request->getModuleName()`)
2. implement the logic in module bootstrap (only for module you need).

#### Edit after update:

You just need to treat modules+controllers as resources, and actions as privileges:

```
$acl->deny('guest', 'adminmodulename:controllername', array('tour', 'hotel'));
```

or for all:

```
$acl->deny('guest', 'adminmodulename:controllername');
```

> isn't there a way to check if resource is registered in acl?

$acl->has($resource)

Comment: could you please explain me how to add resource module

Comment: Resources are just strings. `$acl->addResource('modulenamehere')`. How do you check access to the acl? Controller plugin? Show us the code. What to you want to do? Allow or deny (which?) module?

Comment: hi , i do that idea, like this: `$this->_acl->deny('guest', 'admin:auth' , array('first'));` but it show me this error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Acl_Exception' with message 'Resource 'admin:auth' not found' in E:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Acl.php:347 Stack trace#0 E:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Acl.php(624): Zend_Acl->get('admin:auth') #1 E:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Acl.php(503): Zend_Acl->setRule('OP_ADD', 'TYPE_DENY', 'guest', 'admin:auth', Array, NULL) #2 ...`

Answer (score 1):

That's not a very specific question :)

Anyways... You will probably have to implement a user management yourself for ZF. But don't be afraid, there are tons of tutorials online! ([e.g. here](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3322))

What do you mean by "do i always have to add controller and index?"?

Comment: i have two module default and admin. and they both have many controllers with many actions, cannot i set this access rule simply for the module

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question. I suggest you make your application modular. For the ACL just move it up as well (aka make your modules the resources)!

e.g.

```
// ROLES
$this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest')); // default
$this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('Marketing'), 'guest'); // 15

// RESOURCES (MY MODULES)
$this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('auth'));
$this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('takeon'));

// PRIVILEGES
//
// default
$this->deny();
//
// guest
$this->allow('guest', 'auth');
// 15 Marketing
$this->allow('Marketing', 'default');
$this->allow('Marketing', 'takeon', array('index', 'ben10cards'));
```

Then in your plugin use:

```
// OBTAIN CONTROL LIST
$acl = new Auth_Model_Acl();

// OBTAIN RESOURCE
$module = $request->getModuleName();
$controller = $request->getControllerName();
// VALIDATE
if ($acl->isAllowed($role, $module, $controller)) {
    $allowed = true;
```

You might then not have resources available for actions, but works better for me :)